# PrimeNG - npm WARN on dependencies - version update

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, primeng

I have to update my PrimeNG version to the latest version which is: 1.0.0-rc.2
I used before the following package.json which is working fine:

```
{
"name": "primeng",
"version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "client-http": "0.0.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10",
    "primeng": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "primeui": "4.1.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.9"
}
}
```

Updating my PrimeNG version to the latest version, I also added some new dependencies. After update, my package.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "primeng",
"version": "1.0.0-rc.2",
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "client-http": "0.0.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10",
    "primeng": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "primeui": "4.1.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.9"
}
}
```

After npm install I see some WARN-s in console.

```
npm WARN @angular/common@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.14 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@~0.1.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.14 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.14 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.26 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-http-client@0.2.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-http-client@0.2.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.25 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-http-client@0.2.0 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN primeng@1.0.0-rc.2 No repository field.
```

How I can fix this problem? If I'm changing the library versions I receive other WARN-s conflicts

Comment: always make your `angular` packages the same version. In this case `2.0.2`. Or go to the most recent: `2.1.2`. You can ignore the warnings primeng will give you. I'm pretty sure it will work

Comment: Updatind al @angular versions to 2.1.2 and the primeng version to 1.0.1, and running the application there missing some .js files like core.js, common.js, forms.js, router.js.